# How to delete folder with \ in name?

Tags: directory

I used pscp to copy files from my pc to my server.
Because my pc here is running windows and the server is on linux, i kind of messed up the \ and / and as it happens, in my server there is now a folder named

```
\home\profile\\blabla\
```

It appears when i `ls` or `ll`, but i cannot delete it.

Does anybody know how to get rid of it?

Comment: What command did you use to remove it? What was the output of that command? Please edit your answer to include that information.

Comment: i used `rm -r`. output was that it couldnt find it.
Jos answer worked though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find its inode number:

`stat '\home\profile\\blabla\'`

Then remove it by its inode:

`find . -inum [inode-number] -exec rm -i {} \;`

This will pass the inode number to `rm`.